# Find a time difference to the following row

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

How to find the time difference in minutes among different columns with different source IDs

```
No SourceID  RecordID  Start Date               End Date
1  1         1         2009-09-07 09:12:00.0000 2009-09-07 11:00:00.0000 
2  1         1         2009-09-07 11:19:00.0000 2009-09-07 12:12:00.0000  
3  1         1         2009-09-07 12:23:00.0000 2009-09-07 12:54:00.0000  
4  1         1         2009-09-07 13:49:00.0000 2009-09-07 14:45:00.0000 
5  2         2         2009-10-12 09:12:00.0000 2009-10-12 11:00:00.0000  
6  2         2         2009-10-12 11:19:00.0000 2009-10-12 12:12:00.0000
7  2         2         2009-10-12 12:23:00.0000 2009-10-12 12:54:00.0000
```

How to get the difference between EndDate of first record with Start Date of next record and same for different source ID and how to fill the empty space with "-1" and then update into a column?

here result needs get as

```
 SourceID  RecordID  Start Date               End Date                 DiffMin
 1         1         2009-09-07 09:12:00.0000 2009-09-07 11:00:00.0000 19 
 1         1         2009-09-07 11:19:00.0000 2009-09-07 12:12:00.0000 11 
 1         1         2009-09-07 12:23:00.0000 2009-09-07 12:54:00.0000 55 
 1         1         2009-09-07 13:49:00.0000 2009-09-07 14:45:00.0000 NULL
 2         2         2009-10-12 09:12:00.0000 2009-10-12 11:00:00.0000 19 
 2         2         2009-10-12 11:19:00.0000 2009-10-12 12:12:00.0000 11
 2         2         2009-10-12 12:23:00.0000 2009-10-12 12:54:00.0000 55
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably want to use an analytic function along these lines:

```
postgres=# SELECT No, SourceID, RecordID, StartDate, EndDate
postgres-#       ,LEAD(StartDate) OVER(PARTITION BY SourceID ORDER BY StartDate) - EndDate AS diff
postgres-#   FROM myTable;
 no | sourceid | recordid |      startdate      |       enddate       |   diff
----+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------
  1 |        1 |        1 | 2009-09-07 09:12:00 | 2009-09-07 11:00:00 |  00:19:00
  2 |        1 |        1 | 2009-09-07 11:19:00 | 2009-09-07 12:12:00 |  00:11:00
  3 |        1 |        1 | 2009-09-07 12:23:00 | 2009-09-07 12:54:00 |  00:55:00
  4 |        1 |        1 | 2009-09-07 13:49:00 | 2009-09-07 14:45:00 |
  5 |        2 |        2 | 2009-10-12 09:12:00 | 2009-10-12 11:00:00 |  00:19:00
  6 |        2 |        2 | 2009-10-12 11:19:00 | 2009-10-12 12:12:00 |  00:11:00
  7 |        2 |        2 | 2009-10-12 12:23:00 | 2009-10-12 12:54:00 |
(7 rows)
```

Comment: This is showing time difference in negative, Please let me know How can I get it into positive. Thanks a lot for Help.

Comment: @ParveenArora . . . Just reverse the subtraction . . . `lead() . . - EndDate`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Now its showing syntax error.  (syntax error at or near "OVER")

Comment: @ParveenArora -- my guess is you didn't reverse all of the `LEAD` function:  `LEAD(StartDate) OVER(PARTITION BY SourceID ORDER BY StartDate) - EndDate`...

Comment: Updated.  Was just meant to be an example of the functions you can use. You will probably wish to do some manipulation on the border conditions, using COALESCE to handle nulls, specifying what the true partitions are (for example, I'm not clear on how sourceid and recordid differ...). etc

Comment: "Analytic functions" is a term Oracle uses. Postgres talks about ["window functions"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) - which really makes more sense IMO.

Comment: @Glenn Yeah I was not using the brackets properly for manipulation. Thanks and for source ID, Lets consider a car rent company with different cars and each car is having own source ID.

At the empty places where its not showing any result, I want to add -1 at the places and then update  the result into a newly created column. Please give me some idea about that.   Thanks a lot :)